# MySQL Fulltext Search, increase minimum character

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to do MySQL fulltext search using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ($q) limit $limit
```

The problem is, if any words under 4 characters are included in the search phrase than it ignores them. This is very bad for my search engine because a lot of possible things people will be searching for will include 3 and sometimes even 2 letter words.

I read somewhere that it was possible to change this in MySQL settings but after searching around I can't find any information on how to do this.. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [this page in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) -- basically you set ft_min_word_len=3 (or 2), restart the server, and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: ok but then how do you rebuild the fulltext search index as the manual suggests?

Comment: If you read to the bottom of the linked page, it suggests a few ways ... REPAIR TABLE or ALTER TABLE with DROP INDEX then again with ADD INDEX, etc.

Comment: I don't understand where do I go to change it? phpmyadmin? terminal, where?

Comment: You change it in my.conf most likely located in /etc/, then restart MySQL or MariaDB. You don't need to restart the server. To do the re-index just run this
REPAIR TABLE `table_name`;